# Touchpad not detected via evtest on a Samsung 300V5A Series 3

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, samsung

Having to use usb mouse, another release and another major bug..

samsung 300V5, appeared in default 12.04 install

Comment: I attached to a wired connection and reboot and tried installing the drivers which were available and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those with similar issues, there was a recent update to 12.04 (yes post release) this upgraded the kernel and headers etc.. so now the touchpad is detected

NOTE : it is detected on this particular laptop as '  ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad '

hope this helps someone